# MySQL - Order field alphabetically first and then decimally

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a `VARCHAR name` field in my database that contains both characters and decimals to represent version numbers of software. **Given the example data below, how can I order the results in the correct order?**

```
name
--------------------
Version 1.7
Version 1.8
Version 1.9
Version 1.10
Version 2.2
Version 3.0
Version 3.3
```

The problem, by default, is that ordering the results by `name` only, results in something like this:

```
name
--------------------
Version 1.10
Version 1.7
Version 1.8
Version 1.9
Version 2.2
Version 3.0
Version 3.3
```

This has been asked before on StackOverflow and I've been through and tested many of the answers provided but without luck. It's also difficult to find a solution that works for a similar result set, namely a mix of alphanumerical and decimal.

**I have tried:**

```
ORDER BY CAST(name AS INTEGER)
ORDER BY CAST(name AS DECIMAL)
ORDER BY CAST(name AS DECIMAL(4,2)
- same as above but CONVERT(name, [type])
ORDER BY ABS(name)
- some other things which have since slipped my mind :/
```

**Things to note:**

- The `name` field is not always prefixed with 'Version'. Sometimes
  it's 'Deprecated' or a number of other things.
- The `name` field does not always contain decimal version numbers. It can sometimes be a word on its own.
- The `name` field could also contain items like `Plugin Name 2` and `Go2URL`.
- The problem item is 'Version 1.10'. All of the methods I have tried so far have led to this item being out of place.

**Workaround:**

I've worked around this issue temporarily by adding a new `VARCHAR` field called `canonicalVersion` and storing a canonical version number. So, `1.10.210` becomes `0001.0010.0210.0000` and is therefore simply sortable with `ORDER BY canonicalVersion ASC` and all items are now in the correct order.

Although I've worked around the issue for now, I would still like to see a solution to the original question without adding an extra field.

Comment: The stated duplicate is not a duplicate of this question.  This has variable length prefixes and there are not multiple levels for the versions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `substring_index()` and some manipulation:

```
order by left(name, length(name) - length(substring_index(name, ' ', -1)) - 1),
         substring_index(name, ' ', -1) + 0
```

This assumes that the version numbers themselves can be converted to numbers.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at and answer my question. I have just tried your solution which results in the following error: '... check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') + 0' at line 2'. I removed the trailing `)` from the end of last `order by` clause which got it working but the order of the results are still incorrect, with `1.10` coming out first.